# problema con un arreglo en c++

Tags: c++

estoy intentando hacer el juego de adivina la palabra, pero tengo esta leyenda Member reference base type 'char [4]' is not a structure or union, al querer meter en un for, el tamaño, con secreta.size(); me da error, y no entiendo el porque, si quito esa variable difinida, y pongo cualquier otro numero no me da error.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void word(string);
char secreta[]={'h','o','l','a'};
void search(char);
int vidas=4;
int aux=4;

int main() {
    char letra;
    cout<<"Palabra: ";
    word(secreta);

    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Juego iniciado"<<endl;
    cout<<"Digite una letra para adivinar"<<endl;
    search(letra);
    return 0;
}

void word(string secreta){

    for(int i=0; i<secreta.size(); i++){
        cout<<"*";
    }

}
void search(char letra){

    for(int i=0; i<secreta.size(); i++){
        cout<<"Numero de vidas: "<<aux--<<endl;
        cin>>letra;

        if(letra==secreta[i]){
            cout<<"Letra adivinada "<<secreta[i]<<endl<<"Siguiente: ";
        }else{
            cout<<"Fallaste "<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: En la función `void search()` estás llamando a `char secreta []`, y éste es un array que no tiene el método `size`. Esto es así porque ese array secreta está definido de forma global, y al no haber una variable local dentro de tu función con el nombre secreta (entiendo que quieres usar `string secreta` pues usa la variable global.

Answer (score 2):

En este caso es mejor calcular el largo del array, ya que no esta definido. Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
void search(char letra){
 
  int arrSize = sizeof(secreta)/sizeof(secreta[0]); 
 
    for(int i=0; i<arrSize; i++){
        cout<<"Numero de vidas: "<<aux--<<endl;
        cin>>letra;

        if(letra==secreta[i]){
            cout<<"Letra adivinada "<<secreta[i]<<endl<<"Siguiente: ";
        }else{
            cout<<"Fallaste "<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: que significa esto? sizeof(secreta)/sizeof(secreta[0]);

Answer (score 2):

En [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), las formaciones<sup>1</sup> son una [estructura de datos pasiva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_data_structure). Esto significa que no tiene métodos asociados, por lo tanto: `secreta.size()` no es válido, y eso te está diciendo el compilador (te lo traduzco):

> Member reference base type 'char [4]' is not a structure or union

> La referencia con tipo básico 'char [4]' no es una estructura o unión

Básicamente te dice que el tipo `'char [4]'` no es un tipo de dato que pueda tener funciones miembro. Pero puedes averiguar el tamaño de una formación con [`std::extent`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent) de [`<type_traits>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits):

```
for (int i = 0; i < std::extent_v<decltype(secreta)>; ++i) {
//                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- Calcula el tamaño de la formación
    cout<<"*";
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.